# Auto renewing in app purchase not getting any expired notification in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, in-app-purchase

I have implemented apple auto renewal subscription in my app but have not get any expiry notification from webhook. Can someone please help me?

Comment: while receipt validation you will get the expiry date you can use it anywhere.

Comment: Won't I get a webhook notification when the product expires?

Answer (score 1):

At the WWDC21, they announced a new Server-To-Server Notification (S2S) called `EXPIRED` (https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2021/10174/?time=1030). This S2S will have different substates to know the expiration's cause: `VOLUNTARY`, `BILLING_RETRY` and `PRICE_INCREASE`.

With current S2S, you have different S2S, that won't cover all the cases:

- `CANCEL`: Indicates that either Apple customer support canceled the subscription or the user upgraded their subscription. The `cancellation_date` key contains the date and time of the change.
- `DID_FAIL_TO_RENEW`: Indicates a subscription that failed to renew due to a billing issue. Be cautious, when a grace period is defined, it doesn't always mean the subscription has expired ([more info here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/original_api_for_in-app_purchase/subscriptions_and_offers/reducing_involuntary_subscriber_churn))
- `REFUND`: Indicates that App Store successfully refunded a transaction.
- `REVOKE`: Indicates that an in-app purchase the user was entitled to through Family Sharing is no longer available through sharing. StoreKit sends this notification when a purchaser disabled Family Sharing for a product, the purchaser (or family member) left the family group, or the purchaser asked for and received a refund.

That's why, to ensure you revoke the access of a subscriber when the subscription expires, you have to re-check the subscription's validity with [/verifyReceipt](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appstorereceipts/verifyreceipt). S2S won't be enough until the new S2S arrive. And even then, you should always check manually since you could miss a S2S because of errors on your side or on Apple side.

I've written a full article on the subject that should help you fully understand this difficult subject: [How to detect an expired subscription on the different app stores](https://www.purchasely.com/blog/how-to-detect-an-expired-subscription-on-the-different-app-stores).

Comment: how do I check manually? suppose I have a receipt when I purchased the product but the receipt returns only till the purchase, I guess it does not shows the renewed transaction. I cannot get the subscription expired when it has been renew as I only have the data till initial purchase.

Comment: Everything is explained here: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/original_api_for_in-app_purchase/validating_receipts_with_the_app_store

Comment: Does the Apple dispatch plan expire notification after the plan cancellation?
Bcz, I got AUTO_RENEWABLE_DISABLED notification immediately after the user initiated the cancellation. after that, I don't receive any notification including the final plan expiration. Is this the correct scenario?